# Which digraphs are morally unambiguous?

Tags: graph-theory

All my digraphs are reflexive and have no parallel arcs.

**Intuition.** Think of the vertexes as people. An arc $x \rightarrow y$ means "$x$ would care about $y$ if $x$ knew and understood $y$" or, more simply "$x$ cares about $y$." The good people are the ones that care about every other good person. More formally:

> **Definition 0.** Given a digraph, call a subset $G$ of the vertexes of that digraph a "candidate for the set of good people" iff the following two axioms hold.

0, *Mutuality.* Good people care about each other; i.e. for all $x,y \in G$, we have that $x \rightarrow y$.

1, *Saturation.* If you care about all good people, then you yourself are good; i.e. for each vertex $x$ of the digraph, if "for all $y \in G$ we have $x \rightarrow y$," then $x \in G$.

Note that these can be combined into a single axiom:

**Axiom.** For each vertex $x$ of the digraph, $x \in G$ iff for all $y \in G$ we have $x \rightarrow y.$

> **Definition 1.** Call a digraph *morally ambiguous* iff it has many candidates for the set of good people, or none. Otherwise, it is *morally unambiguous.*

For example, morally speaking:

- The discrete (reflexive) digraph on $2$ vertexes is ambiguous.
- The complete (reflexive) digraph on $2$ vertexes is unambiguous.

> **Question.** Is there a decent characterization of those digraphs that are morally unambiguous?
>
> I'm also interested in necessary and sufficient conditions.

My gut feeling is that this question should be pretty easy: we should be able to solve it just by thinking about the existence of complete subgraphs enjoying certain relationships to the other vertexes. I haven't been able to make this intuition precise, though.

Comment: The definition itself seems pretty simple, and I don't see any reason to expect there to be a simpler characterization.

Comment: Interestingly, $G$ has an *impredicative* definition: membership in the set is defined by reference to all the elements of the set :) Whether it actually characterizes "good" people is another question entirely. Isn't "morally unambiguous" the same thing as "has exactly one complete subgraph"?

Comment: Why did you delete $y\in G$ under mutuality? What's $y$ now? Is an existential or universal quantification over it implied?

Comment: @joriki, that was just a typo I accidentally introduced :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really consider this to be any nicer than the definition itself, but maybe this is what you are looking for.  It is easy to see that $G$ is a candidate iff $G$ is a complete subgraph such that for any $x\not\in G$, there is some $y\in G$ such that $x\not\to y$.  So a graph is unambiguous iff it contains exactly one complete subgraph with this property.

Note that the analogue for *undirected* graphs does have a much simpler description: then candidates are exactly the maximal complete subgraphs, so a graph is unambiguous iff it has a unique maximal complete subgraph.  Since every vertex is contained in a some maximal complete subgraph, this means the graph must be complete.

Comment: It seems maximality is built into the definition of "goodness" (the Axiom form).The Axiom also implies that every $x \in G$ has a loop $x \to x$ -- that's stated at the top of the question, but it also follows from, um, "AG".